# Publishing messages to SNS directly from the browser with AWS SDK for JavaScript V3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is there a way to publish messages to SNS directly from the browser? I was thinking that AWS SDK for JavaScript could do it but I understand that node.js must be used.

Comment: The bigger issue is that how are you going to expose the SNS topic? Its not a good practice to hardcode any AWS credentials in JS on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks @marcin. Yes, I realize that security is a huge concern here. That is why asking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to front your SNS with **API gateway** endpoint. An example of how to do it is:

- [How do I use API Gateway as a proxy for another AWS service?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-integrate-service/)